# How to schedule a task in java using Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to develop a functionality which will perform a certain task after a specified time. The application will be deployed on JBOSS server. And as soon as I start the server the schedular should be initialised. Currently i have to hit the website first then only it starts. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [QuartzInitializerServlet](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerServlet.html) and ensure you set  `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` in your web.xml